# What is the advantage of the paperboat format in performance optimization of ML?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, dataset

The [paperBoat](http://ismion.net/documentation/paperboat/file_formats.html) format claims to provide a better dataset representation for machine learning routines. I'd like to understand the nature of its optimization. I understand that using an integer representation for model attributes means a faster processing of the data set, what are the other improvements.

Also, how to tune an ML algorithm to work with this file format.

Comment: `optimal dataset representation`?  Now that's a bold claim. To me this sounds more like http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: to capture your comment, I changed optimal to better. PS: the link is very expressive, however, I wish to see a more objective analysis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this format really provides better representation, but I can speculate why it can be more efficient.

First, as they state at format description, "Having data of the same precision consecutive enables hardware vectorization."; consider also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor): "Vector processing techniques have since been added to almost all modern CPU designs".

Second, their format allows you to mix sparse and non-sparse features, but since all sparse features are placed consequently, it is possible to easily take them as a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) and optimize methods for learning like  conjugate gradient.

> how to tune an ML algorithm to work with this file format?

What do you mean by ML algorithm tuning? The learning algorithm doesn't know and doesn't need to know anything about file format of the dataset; and you can't increase or decrease accuracy if you know file format. In theory, you can speed up the concrete  optimization algorithm (like Gradient descent) if you can rely on some properties of data (and, I guess, Ismion PaperBoat does it), but I don't think that you can tune it by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. regarding "tuning ML algorithm" I wanted to ask, if, for instance, I have  a linear regression model, with features being (sales,time,weather,location) , using this dataformat, it seems that i will have to represent my features vector differently and my question is how to go from the first representation to the new representation of the features vector that goes with this data format.

Comment: It is well described at the page you provided; if your format isn't the one of listed 4, you should read file format specification (http://ismion.net/documentation/paperboat/file_formats.html#ismion-file-specification) and write down your features accordingly